# .htaccess file to speed up a website?

Tags: performance, .htaccess, pagespeed

A friend of mine built me a htaccess file and I'm way too much of a noobie at the moment to be able to read and know that it does (exactly). All I know is that it's supposed to do gzip compression and cache my site. When I do a speed test, it says that "Compress gzip" and "Use browser caching", which I was told the htaccess file is supposed to do. It's for a basic HTML website, nothing crazy but I just wanted to clean up some speed issues. Anyway, here is the code for it. If anyone can take a look at it and tell me what's wrong, I would truly appreciate it. If you need more information, I will be happy to post it. Thanks guys!

```
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x- javascript application/javascript
</ifmodule>

<IfModule mod_gzip.c>
    mod_gzip_on Yes
    mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
    mod_gzip_item_include file \.(html?|xml|txt|css|js)$
    mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresByType text/html "access 2 day"
    ExpiresByType text/css "access 2 day"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType text/plain "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
    ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
</IfModule>

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Connection keep-alive
</ifModule>
```

Comment: Please ask the author what it does. As for what is wrong with it, why are you asking us? You are supposed to tell us what is wrong.

Comment: I asked him, he said it's supposed to fix the gzip compression and the caching (thought I was pretty clear on that but I guess I was mistaken), and according to the speed test it is not doing that. I was just curious if it was out of order or if there was something wrong in the way it is coded. Sorry, I guess I wasn't clear on what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Check if the modules (deflate, gzip, etc) are enabled in your `httpd.conf` file.